# How to make DatePickerDialog show up as a spinner instead of calendar?

Tags: android, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have been searching online for a while trying to figure out how to make the spinner DatePickerDialog to appear and I have tried setting android:datePickerMode="spinner" in my xml file but it is still not working. Only the calendar view is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:spinnersShown="true"` and `android:calendarViewShown="false"` to your XML.

Comment: Try with my updated answer. If that doesn't solve it can you please edit your question to show more of your XML?

Comment: I tried your updated answer and I don't think changing the xml will work because I don't actually have a DatePicker view. I am following this tutorial: http://javapapers.com/android/android-datepicker/ . So I don't know if there is some way I can change the mode of DatePickerDialog to spinner. The tutorial has a spinner view present.

Comment: Well if you want proper help then you need to show your code and XML. I can't give you a solution without seeing the problem.